# What is the RegExp Pattern to Extract Bullet Points Between Two Group Words using VBA in Word?

Tags: regex, vba, excel, ms-word

I can't seem to figure out the RegExp to extract the bullet points between two group of words in a word document.

For example:

Risk Assessment:

- Test 1
- Test 2
- Test 3

Internal Audit

In this case I want to extract the bullet points between "Risk Assessment" and "Internal Audit", one bullet at a time and assign that bullet to an Excel cell. As shown in the code below I have pretty much everything done, except I cant figure out the correct Regex pattern. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub PopulateExcelTable()

    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

       With fd

          .AllowMultiSelect = False

          .Title = "Please select the file."

          .Filters.Clear
          .Filters.Add "Word 2007-2013", "*.docx"

          If .Show = True Then
            txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1)

          End If
       End With

    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(txtFileName)

    Dim str As String: str = WordDoc.Content.Text ' Assign entire document content to string

    Dim rex As New RegExp
    rex.Pattern = "\b[^Risk Assessment\s].*[^Internal Audit\s]"

    Dim i As long : i = 1
    rex.Global = True
    For Each mtch In rex.Execute(str)
        Debug.Print mtch
        Range("A" & i).Value = mtch
        i = i + 1
    Next mtch

    WordDoc.Close
    WordApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a long way around the problem but it works.

Steps I'm taking:

1. Find bullet list items using keywords before and after list in regexp.
2. `(`Group`)` regexp pattern so that you can extract everything in-between words.
3. Store listed items group into a string.
4. Split string by new line character into a new array.
5. Output each array item to excel.
6. Loop again since there may be more than one list in document.

*Note: I don't see your code for a link to Excel workbook.  I'll assume this part is working.*

---

```
Dim rex As New RegExp
rex.Pattern = "(\bRisk Assessment\s)(.*)(Internal\sAudit\s)" 
rex.Global = True
rex.MultiLine = True
rex.IgnoreCase = True

Dim lineArray() As String
Dim myMatches As Object
Set myMatches = rex.Execute(str)

For Each mtch In rex.Execute(str)
    'Debug.Print mtch.SubMatches(1)

    lineArray = Split(mtch.SubMatches(1), vbLf)
    For x = LBound(lineArray) To UBound(lineArray)
        'Debug.Print lineArray(x)

        Range("A" & i).Value = lineArray(x)
        i = i + 1
    Next
Next mtch
```

---

My test page looks like this:

[image]

Results from inner `Debug.Print` line return this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Although, I would be particularly interested in a pure RegEx (pure scientific curiosity) it works great, the only thing I have to change was to use Chr(13) instead of vbLF. The split operation was not working correctly with vbLF